# Ghanaian Women to visit US

Tags: international-travel

If a women from Ghana wants to visit the US and she is a first time traveler,will she have to have $5000.00 travelers check in her possession before she can come?

Comment: It's a scam ....

Comment: I don't think this deserves downvotes. You and I may have seen this a thousand times, but I'm sure Gregory has not!

Comment: The short answer, Gregory, is no. The U.S. does not impose any requirement to carry any fixed amount of funds upon any person of any gender from any country.